# window.open causing error in IE only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am calling this from ie8:

```
function verify_ssl()
{
    window.open ("https://seal.godaddy.com/verifySeal?sealID=129275340046e2e09512711f05bc73f617fac022950185486622550",
    "ssl-window","status=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=540,height=435");
}
```

It says invalid argument, It works fine in FF and Chrome. Any idea what the issue is in IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wild guess: Remove the `-` from `ssl-window`.

Comment: Yeah its a bug in IE: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2008/06/bug-289-popup-window-name-cant-have.html

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it (Mac user), but I remember something about the title of window.open (the 2nd parameter), try it without the "-".